# What means "Alle ums Kill"?

Tags: meaning, salutation

Someone greeted me with "Alle ums Kill" as a farewell. *What does that mean?* Hint, it seems to have something to do with archery because it was used in this context.

I assume (assume very hard ;P) that it's something like "Waidmanns Heil" or "Petri Heil".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "normal" greeting among archers might be "Alle ins Gold" ("I wish you success so that **all** your arrows may hit **into the golden** centre of the target"). 
A variant of archery uses 3D animal shapes instead of the usual disk-shaped target with concentric rings. In this variant, there is no "gold" but a "kill" (apparently from the english word). That would make the greeting "Alle ins kill". I suppose you either misheard that, or "Alle ums kill" is an ironic variant.

Comment: Thank you :) That also might explain why I didn't find anything googling for "Alle ums Kill"